# Spark: unpersist rdd before remove it from List

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a list of rdd `List<JavaRDD<MyType>>`. Each rdd in list is cached in memory.

Now I want to remove one of the list items. 
Do I need to call `.unpersist()` on it before `.remove(index)`?

And if "yes": as I know `.unpersist()` uses lazy evaluation. Do I need to run some action and then remove the item? Looks like it doesn't make much sense.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to call .unpersist() on it before .remove(index)

You may and it is probably a good idea to do it, but if you don't it will be handled automatically one object is garbage collected.

> I need to run some action and then remove the item

Definitely not. There is nothing wrong with calling `unpersist` on a RDD which hasn't been persisted and if there is nothing to remove it is better for you.

Comment: About the second park of the question: I mean if I call `unpersist` on cashed rdd - when it will be actually executed? Is `unpersist` uses lazy evaluation too? Because I'm not suppose to call any action on this rdd after `unpersist`.

Comment: It is not lazy but by default it is asynchronous. If you want to make sure it has been completed use blocking version `rdd.unpersist(true)`.